# Making a Triangle from $3$ sides of a Quadrilateral

Tags: combinatorics, triangles, quadrilateral

This problem has stumped me for a little while:

> Given a quadrilateral with integer side lengths, what is the probability that three of its sides can be removed and reassembled to form a triangle?

Of course, this problem will use the fact that each side length of a triangle must be less than the sum of the other two side lengths, and that in a quadrilateral, each side length will be less than the sum of the other three side lengths. But how can I use combinatorics to count this?

Note: I made this problem up, so if it is a "bad problem" (cannot be done) please let me know why.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I think having the requirement that the side lengths be integers makes the problem more difficult.

Comment: Why would that make it more difficult? My intention with adding that to the problem was to make it easier. I can just remove it.

Comment: No, don't remove it. If somebody can find a way to solve the problem for integer side lengths, they will post an answer.

Comment: There is no way to answer this question as-it-is because there is no structure on the involved probability space. We take some "random integer lengths" according to which distribution?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I understand the difficulty there, but I think the question of what the probability is over all possible quadrilaterals is a valid one. (It may be too difficult to answer)

Comment: It is not difficult, it is simply impossible: we still need to define a measure over the set of all the possible quadrilaterals with integer lengths.

Comment: Perhaps I should say "quadrilaterals with side lengths from $1$ to $n$ inclusive", and then the answer would be a formula in terms of $n$.

Comment: what is the probability space?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I think we should find the conditions for constructing a quadrilateral (With $a , b , c $ and $d$ sides which they are integer) .